# How to use Python's OpenSSL lib in order to create RSA pairs and CRS from them?

Tags: python, ssl, rsa, csr

I just had started my studies about SSL recently and I need to create a RSA key pairs, then use'em to create a CSR. It must be done in Python, due my projects needs.

I took a look around several libs and their documentations, as also websites, blogs and some books too, but everything I've found is or only at Linux (which help me to understand better about SSL) or not exacly what I'm looking for.

I also gonna need to validate certificate chains and learn about HTTP GET using HTTPS with certification, but I can take care of that later.

(I don't know, it looks basic stuff but I ain't figuring out anyways)

Any help will be welcome and I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "...Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". Also, you don't actually have a question anywhere in your question.

Comment: Well... it's my first post, so thanks about the advices.

The thing is: I really apreciate a good help and I just don't know how to figure out about creating RSA key pairs and using them to create CSR.

So, yes, maybe it's better question about HOW TO CREATE RSA PAIRS AND CREATE CSR FROM THEM USING PYTHON'S OPENSSL LIB.

Comment: And I've been finding how to figure out, I think. If it's the case, I will update the post with an answer the soon as I can.

Comment: Please read the link I provided.

Comment: Instead of asking a broad question in the hope that others will do the work for you I recommend to simple use a search engine. [python create rsa key](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+create+rsa+key) and [python create csr](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+create+csr)  give enough useful hits.

Comment: Ok, I already had read the link and obviously googled about it. It's good to improve myself about how to make a question here or on Google but I ain't just looking after an answer, I came here looking for a help, even some little ones.

The things I already found didn't work somehow, I've looking for libs at all. The most part of them use the OpenSSL's crypto lib but even installed in the Python (2.7) its do not recognises it.
I've found one called pkiutils, aparently exacly what I've benn looking for, but the PIP don't install it exacly due it need the crypto lib.

Comment: I already made RSA pairs using the rsa lib, but I couldn't make a CSR from them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the idea of using **PKIutils** lib made his effort. I could not installed in the beginning in order of some problems and issues with Python (2.7), but they are now solved.

This lib is really the thing I was looking for and is very simple once it does his job in a basic way with a proportional effort.

As we can see in its docs (http://python-pkiutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), we just need to call as the example:

`key = pkiutils.create_rsa_key(1024, keyfile='')
csr = pkiutils.create_csr
      (key,
      dn="/C=GB/ST=STATENAME/L=LOCAILITY/O=COMPANY/OU=DEPT/CN=www.example.com",
      csrfilename='')`

This is just an example, of course, but it creates the RSA pair and the CSR anyways.

Solved my problem; maybe it can be useful for somebody else.